# Reading a file from a C++ class used in an iOS project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, file-io

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK and I'm also using OpenCV.

I have some C++ classes and I have to read the content of a XML with these C++ classes.

With Objective-C I do it in this way:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"xml"];  
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
if (myData) {  
    // do something useful  
}
```

But, **how can I do it from C++?**

I know that cpp need a file path and I don't know how can I get that path from C++.

All my OpenCV algorithms are in C++ classes, so I have to do it in those C++ classes.

Comment: Why don't you use Objective-C++ and read it the way you always have?

Comment: @trojanfoe Because I have my algorithms implemented in C++.

Comment: And?  Simply rename the `.cpp` to `.mm` and you can mix C++ and Objective-C to your hearts content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Open file in C++ using C string (`[filePath fileSystemRepresentation]` returns `const char*`)
2. Open file in Objective C and then pass pointer to raw bytes and size (`[myData bytes]` and `[myData length`])

Comment: What about the actual parsing of the `plist` file?

Comment: *Remark:* The correct way to get a file system path from NSString is `fileSystemRepresentation`, not `UTF8String`.

Answer (score 1):

While it's, of course, possible to open the XML file and parse it using pure C++, I think you should use Apples-provided Objective-C classes to perform this parsing.  You can do this by using Objective-C++ (i.e. mixed Objective-C and C++) simply by renaming your C++ implementation file extension from `.cpp` to `.mm`.

The reason I think this is a good idea:

1. It's quicker to implement and less error-prone.
2. If changes are made to the `plist` format, you will get those changes for free.

Comment: Those xml files are encoded and I'm migrating an app from Android to iPhone and I want to make C++ compatible, so I can't use Objective-C code here to process the files.